# Новая форма в таймере

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день.

По таймеру каждую минуту запускается метод, в котором создается и отображается новая форма.

Как сделать проверку в методе, что если форма уже создана - не создавать ее вновь?

Спасибо.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    System.Timers.Timer tmr2 = new System.Timers.Timer();
                    tmr2.AutoReset = true;
                    tmr2.Interval = 30000;
                    tmr2.Elapsed += ftp_connect;
                    tmr2.Start();

}

private void ftp_connect(object se, EventArgs o)
        {
            command_class comm = new command_class();
            comm.Message_Show(arrFiles[0]);
       }
}

 class command_class
    {
    public void Message_Show(string file)
    {
    //Объявляем новую форму
     Form message_form = new Form();
     message_form.Name = "Message_form";
     message_form.Text = "Важное сообщение!";
     message_form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
     message_form.Size = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize;
     message_form.Activate();
     message_form.ShowDialog();
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ваша форма, как удобнее, так и делайте. Хоть переменную заведите, хоть мютекс создавайте. Или есть подводный камень?

Первое, что в голову пришло...

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer t1 = new Timer() { Interval = 5000, Enabled = true };
        Form frm = null;
        t1.Tick += (s, args) =>
        {
            if (frm != null)
                return;
            frm = new Form();
            frm.ShowDialog();
            frm = null;
        };
        t1.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Обновил первый пост. Этот код вызывается каждую минуту, можете ли привести пример проверки? Т.е. проблема в том что с каждой новой интерацией таймера создается и отображается новая форма.

Comment: Кстати, Activate() есть смысл поднимать только на отображаемой форме. Технически он SetForegroundWindow выполняет, что на невидимом окне, понятное дело, бесполезно)

Comment: Спасибо, только ситуация несколько другая, есть таймер, он запускает метод из класса уже в котором объявляется и отображается форма. Т.е. если я правильно понимаю Ваш пример необходимо объявить форму вне метода?
p.s. обновил еще раз первый пост для наглядности.

Comment: Вы правильно понимаете. Что-то объявить придётся, так как если речь будет только о локальных переменных, то проверять в общем-то будет нечего. Не обязательно форму выносить, можете создать хоть

    Boolean myFormVisible;

Comment: Благодарю, теперь все понятно, решение оказалось таким простым))) Спасибо.

Comment: Исходя из того, что Вы ещё дописали, можно проверку повесить на не пустоту переменной comm.

В своём примере же я использовал лямбду, которая за меня сделала всю рутину по созданию промежуточного класса. В Вашем случае переменную comm с типом command_class можно вынести за пределы метода ftp_connect

Comment: Не за что. Не забывайте отмечать вопрос как решённый.